# Send specific php variable by ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have many items, I want to post the specific item information after click using ajax. Usually I store its information by attribute data-name, data-date, etc.  I use jquery to get it by `.attr()`.  I do not know how to do it if the text is too long or if each item has an array of text `{"Text1", "Text2","Text3"...."Text20"}`. I can not store it as an attribute. I can not figure out where to put it or how & how to get by jQuery?

my Items look very simple like this

```
 <div class="item">
  <a data-name="item1" data-available="1" data-color="blue">Item1</a>
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  <a data-name="item2" data-available="1" data-color="pink">Item2</a>
 </div>
```

This is my jquery

```
 jQuery(".item a").on('click', function () {  
          var url = "/test.php";          
          var item_name = jQuery(this).attr("data-name");    

          jQuery("#display").html("<img id='loading_gif' src='/loading.gif'>");
          jQuery("#display").load(url,{item_name:item_name});  
          return false; 
    });
```

Comment: if your attribute value is too long, you may need a `<input type="hidden"/>` to store the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send json data to your php file using ajax,

```
jQuery(".item a").on('click', function () {
    var available = $(this).attr("data-available"),
        color = $(this).attr("data-color");

    $.ajax({
        url: 'url_to_your_phpfile.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            avail: available,
            color: color
        },
        success: function (data){
            console.log(data); // do something 
        }
    });
}
```

And in your PHP file, you can fetch the variable by simply using `$_POST['avail']` and `$_POST['color']`

**EDIT**

Since you want to access your data from php to your javascript, you can store that to a javascript variable, for example

```
<?php 
    $products = array(
       array("id" => 1, "name" => "Item 1", "color" => "red",  "desc" => "some large text..."),
       array("id" => 2, "name" => "Item 2", "color" => "blue", "desc" => "some large text...")
    );
    echo '<script>var products = '.json_encode($products).'</script>';
    // and then display 
    foreach($products as $product):
      echo '<div class="item"><a data-id="'.$product->id.'"  data-color="'.$product->color.'">'.$product->name.'</a></div>';
    endforeach;
```

And I assume your javascript file will always be on the footer area of your page so, you can always call the `products` variable on your javascript code.
In your JS, you can always add a custom function to find your product by its ID

```
function findProduct(id){
    var product = products.filter(function (product){
        if(product.id == id){
            return product;
        }
    });
    return products.length > 0 ? products[0] : product;
}

$('.item a').on('click', function () {
    // get the id
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    // now, make a function that finds other data for that product with that ID 
    var product = findProduct(id); // finds a product from variable products 
    // product variable will now contain id, name, color, desc and
    // can be accessed directly with product.id, product.desc, etc.
});
```

Comment: Hi dexterb, thanks for answering, I mean I already can post date-available.. but incase the value is too long text or it is an array, I do not know how to store it then later get it by jquery, if I also put it as atrribute then each my  <a> tag is very big

Comment: Hi @Yoona, I added an edit to my answer, and you don't have to put them as an attribute to each of your `a` tag besides the `id` or any unique identifier you use.